# List view TabNavigation Issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to fix tabbing sequence between line items, limit it to only tab through 'text  boxes' only. how to fix this in Listview.

Comment: Can you post more information about the result that you want to get? A pic or something can also help

Answer (score 0):

I found the result of this issue:

```
  <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
```